# No Such Object available on this agent at this OID

Tags: linux, centos, snmp, snmpd

i installed a snmpd into a CentOS 7 minimal installation for system parameters search, for instance:

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
```

for the above command i get the following result:

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

the iptables in this machine is completely open (Lab VM). Is there any snmpd.conf configuration that must be done to enable the read on specific OID's? The documentation i found about SNMP is really dense and i'm kinda lost haha! Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Back to the very basic, you need to learn what is scalar object and what is not. `IF-MIB::ifDescr` is not scalar, so you might use `snmpwalk`, but not `snmpget`. Without knowing such, you won't easily know which command to use or how the data can be interpreted. To avoid losing in internet search, you might start from a good enough book like Essential SNMP.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @LexLi i tried using snmpwalk but came across the same mistake =/ , i''l give the book a check . Thanks for the help tough!

Comment: Use snmpgetnext instead of snmpget.

Comment: @UweInnh `snmptable` (or `snmpwalk`) would be appropriate. `snmpgetnext` still only gives you one value (at most).